# GraphQL - Defining default value for type definitions

Tags: graphql

I am currently working on a project that allows users to log their workouts. I have created this type and input definition for each set they will log (which will link to a corresponding exercise):

```
type Set {
  id: ID!
  reps: Int!
  weight: Float!
}

input SetInput {
  reps: Int!
  weight: Float!
}
```

When users input the weight value on the client side, I want them to be able to choose between the kilograms (kg) and pounds (lb) metric. This made me realise I would need a default metric/value on the server side so it doesn't confuse users on the weight they had done for a set, when they retrieve their workout logs.

Is there a way to set a default metric (e.g. kg) for the weight?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* provide a default value for an input field when defining an input object type:

```
enum Unit {
  KG
  LB
}

input SetInput {
  reps: Int!
  weight: Float!
  unit: Unit = KG
}
```

However, this only means that the value of `unit` will be `KG` if the field is omitted when making whatever request that utilizes this input type. It's up to your server logic to persist the `unit` value and return it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, does this mean I can just leave this default value out and let my resolver code (server logic) do the conversion before storing into my database, so that it is always in kg?

Comment: As the user shouldn't be able to omit this field when entering the weight

Comment: You're conflating your API with your UI. If you want to make it so the user can't omit the field, then that's something you can do on your front end, regardless of whether you have a default in the schema or not.